# Why do I have to do a return here?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-query, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

I wrote a function to fetch a user. And I return the user.
But when I call the function with TanstackQuery the data is undefinded.
When I add a return statement in the useQuery() function it works.

Here is my code that works:

```
export const getUserById = async (userId: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/user/${userId}`);

    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

```
const { data = [], isSuccess } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['user'],
    queryFn: async () => {
      if (userId) {
        const user = await getUserById(userId);
        return user;
      }
    },
    enabled: !!userId,
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
const { data = [], isSuccess } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['user'],
  queryFn: () => {
    if (userId) {
      getUserById(userId);
    }
  },
 enabled: !!userId,
});
```

Comment: How do you expect `useQuery` to get hold of the data (so it can cache it, return it to your component, and everything else the hook does) if you **don't** return it?!

Comment: @Quentin I saw some tutorials, where they didn't do it with a return inside `useQuery`. But I may be wrong. Now I know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's [how the library tells you to use it](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery):

> `queryFn: (context: QueryFunctionContext) => Promise<TData>`
>
> - Required,
>   but only if no default query function has been defined See Default
>   Query Function for more information.
> - The function that the query will
>   use to request data.
> - Receives a QueryFunctionContext
> - ***Must return a
>   promise that will either resolve data or throw an error. The data
>   cannot be undefined.***

Comment: Dang. Didn't see that. I was confused, because I watched some tutorials, where they didn't do that. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jonas maybe you saw something like `queryFn: () => getUserById(userId)` which does a return without a literal `return` statement?

Comment: @MrHerbes That is possible, i don't remember exactly. But I tried your solution and now it works :)
Thanks for your help again!